# Referring to BOOL values in Objective-C methods

Tags: objective-c, boolean

this is a small portion of the code:

```
@interface
BOOL isCarryingmallet;

@implementation

-(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon {
   return isCarryingMallet;
}

-(int)getWeaponDamage {
    if (isCarryingMallet) 
        return kVikingMalletDamage;
    else
        return kVikingFistDamage;
}
```

I don't understand how this works. Does `return isCarryingmMallet;` return YES or NO? Why isn't there an `== YES` in if `(isCarryingMallet)`? Why is it `if (isCarryingMallet)` not `if (isCarryingWeapon)`.
Thanks for answering my newb questions!

Comment: Upvote for obligatory RPG fighting game when learning a new language. My first Obj-C was called "Medieval Combat" :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isCarryingWeapon` method returns the value of the `isCarryingMallet` variable. If there were other possible weapons, that method could return a more complicated value, like `(isCarryingMallet || isCarryingPlasmaCannon)`. Basically right now the only weapon that matters to this class is the mallet. When the `isCarryingWeapon` method is called, this class says to itself, "Am I carrying a mallet?" If so, it knows it's carrying a weapon, so it returns true - "Yes, I've got a weapon." Otherwise it returns false.

As for the `if` question - all `if` statements do is determine whether the value in the parentheses evaluates to true or false. Equality statements are pretty common in if statements but they're not at all required. More specifically, anything that is not 0, null, or nil is true. So the following will all execute the code in the curly braces:

```
if (1) {...}
if (37) {...}
if (YES) {...}
if (true) {...}
```

Boolean variables are often named with the prefix `is` so that this makes natural grammatical sense. In your case, you can parse

```
if (isCarryingMallet) {...}
```

as

> If this guy is carrying a mallet, then...

Comment: Thank you! As of this code right now would it still be able to function if the isCarryingWeapon method wasn't there?

Comment: That all depends on how this class is used elsewhere. If other functions are calling isCarryingWeapon, you couldn't just get rid of it. But this class would work fine without it generally speaking.

Answer (score 0):

method `isCarryingWeapon` returns the value of `isCarryingSword` boolean.

In `getWeaponDamage` method you don't need to do an explicit comparison such as `isCarryingMallet == TRUE` because the if statement will check directly the value of `isCarryingMallet` and that value will be used as the result of a comparison. In other words, if it is TRUE the if statement will behave the same as if it made a comparison between two values and that comparison returned TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't there an "== YES" in "if (isCarryingMallet)"?

By default, statements inside **if** gets executed only if the condition is true. So,

```
if (isCarryingMallet) { /* ... */ }
```

Depending on the value of `isCarryingMallet`, the statements are executed. Think like this -

```
if ( true ) { /* ... */ } // if isCarryingMallet value is true
```

Comment: ohh. So what does -(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon do then?

Comment: it returns the value of isCarryingMallet.  Apparently, according to this code, if one is carrying a mallet, they are carrying a weapon.

Answer (score 0):

> Does "return isCarryingMallet;" return YES or NO?

Do you mean which value is returned? We don't know. The **value is not set in your code** snippet.

Your code snippet assumes that somewhere else we will find some code setting that variable to YES or NO (actually numbers, not text or a true Boolean, as C and Objective-C lack a true Boolean).