# Help on Objective-C BOOL methods

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help on Objective-C BOOL methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850836/help-on-objective-c-bool-methods)

```
@interface

BOOL isCarryingmallet;

@implementation

-(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon {
   return isCarryingMallet;
}

-(int)getWeaponDamage {
    if (isCarryingMallet) 
        return kVikingMalletDamage;
    else
        return kVikingFistDamage;
}
```

I know that the `-(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon` returns `isCarryingWeapon`, but I don't know why that's useful. Can someone give me an example of it?

Also, what does `continue;`do in an if statement?

Thanks you!

Comment: Wow, no kidding. ***Exact*** duplicate.

Comment: I just noticed too but he is asking something different just using same example code

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask a different question about the same code. I should've explained that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `-(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon` actually returns a bool. The type a method returns is whats specified in the brackets. e.g. `(void)` is nothing `(NSString)` would be a string.

`-(BOOL)isCarryingWeapon {
   return isCarryingMallet;
}`

actually returns the value of isCarryingMallet. So calling `[myObject isCarryingWeapon]` would give you a YES or NO based on the value of `isCarryingMallet`.

Continue is used in loops for example

```
for (item in items)
{
    if(item == NULL)
        continue;
    else
        break;
}
```

continue means continue the loop on the next item from the start of the loop. break means stop looping. So you could use these in searching loops. If the item is not what you want you can continue to loop, if you find the item you want you could break ending the looping cycle early.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to access the `isCarryingMallet` property from another class. You could also use accessor methods like this to make the property independent of an actual `BOOL` variable, for example, if you later decide that you want to store the carried weapons in a list, you could still use the same method to determine whether that list is empty and wouldn't have to change any external code that relies on the method.

`continue` doesn't do anything in an `if` statement, except causing a compiler error if the if statement is not part of a loop. It continues the execution at the top of the loop at the top otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In an `if` statement, `continue` does not do anything. But if the `if` is inside a loop (`for`, or `while`, or `do`), then `continue` jumps to the beginning of the loop body, like it always does.

> but I don't know why that's useful

This is an example of data hiding, IMHO. The interface of the class has an `isCarryingWeapon` method which the class consumers are welcome to call. If the class implementation is some day extended to allow for swords, you can change the content of [isCarryingWeapon] method to something like:

```
return isCarryingMallet || isCarryingSword;
```

and the callers won't know the difference.